# Bypass login between each scenario?

Tags: selenium, rspec, automation, capybara

I am using rspec/capybara here.

I'd like to be able to log into the system only once, then run a bunch of scenarios.  Should a scenario fail, it can effectively move onto the next one.

The problem is that once a scenario fails, a new browser session is started and I am asked to log in again.  Is there a way around this?

How is this type of testing handled?  Many systems require a user to log in first prior to exercising all its functions/features.

Answer (score 0):

So many ways to achieve this but I myself prefer a new instance per spec at least if not context or sometimes even it. I like atomic self contained tests.

Anyway, if you decide want to do this, then you could;

- Reuse a cookie session between tests but still open a new browser. Obviously this depends upon the system under test
- Create a global Before all which only creates a browser and sign in if you are not already signed in.
- Create a global After all which navigates to a known state (eg. Home page) but doesn't log out.

There are many approaches which could work